# Angular ionic app : dependency error trying to angular-pouchdb

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, pouchdb

I am trying to work with angular-pouchdb, I am following the install guide here
https://github.com/angular-pouchdb/angular-pouchdb

I did :

```
ionic add angular-pouchdb
```

but I try to put pouchdb as a module dependency in my app, I get a dependency error :

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.25/$injector/modulerr?p0=BoardLine&p1=Error…%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8102%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.min.js%3A49%3A170)(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.min.js:37(anonymous function) @ ...
```

app.js :

```
angular.module('BoardLine', ['ionic', 'pouchdb', 'ngCookies', 'ui.unique', 'BoardLine.controllers', 'BoardLine.services', 'BoardLine.filters'])
```

Can you help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to include pouch in your application with a script on your index.html page. Perhaps like this, if that's where ionic installed it:

```
<script src="lib/angular-pouchdb/angular-pouchdb.js"></script>
```

or maybe like this from a CDN:

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/pouchdb/4.0.3/pouchdb.min.js"></script>
```

I wonder if ionic could work with require to make this sort of thing simpler.

Comment: Indeed, Thanks @Robert